# How to select child of parent with specific class with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select a child based on its class and then do things with it. I am not able to do that. I am only able to do it with the index like so:

```
.children().eq([index])
```

---

```
<div class="container>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col></div>
    </div>
    </div>

        <script>
    $(document).on('click','.col',(e)=>{
    parent = $(e.target).parent().parent()
    $(parent).children('.row').hide()

    })
    </script>
```

I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) will only return immediate parents one level up. What you need is [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to avoid having to chain `parent`calls:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.col', (e) => {
   $(e.target).closest('.container').children('.row').hide()
});
```

Similarly, [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) only works for immediate children, for nested elements you need [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Note that your delegate element is your base element for the search, so you could use that directly instead of traversing the dom:

```
$(e.delegateTarget).children('.row').hide()
```

```js
$('.container').on('click', '.col', (e) => {
  $(e.delegateTarget).children('.row').hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">This will be hidden</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="col">This wont be hidden</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">This will be hidden</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `find()`

```
$(document).on('click','.col',(e)=>{
  $(e.target)
     .parent()
     .find('>.row')
     .hide()
})
```

Comment: Will find do the action to all divs with the same class?

Comment: @user10501411 yes

Comment: I do not want that. I only want it to do that with div with the class within parent

Comment: Let's assume that there are more rows but they are not children.

Comment: @user10501411 can you please update your question to show the structure of the html, and the class names assigned to rows/columns so we can better understand what you're needing?

Comment: @user10501411 Updated my answer. You can find only child elements if you parent div with `>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need is

```
$(document).on('click','.col',function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();   
});
```

Or to keep using arrow function

```
$(document).on('click','.col',(e)=>{
    $(e.relatedTarget).parent().hide()
})
```